# Getting error : java.lang.SecurityException: PID 11584 does not have permission

Tags: android, automation, appium

I am trying to launch the google on the android device(Mi Pro) using appium.But i am getting the permission denied error even i have toggled on the USB debugging in the Developer options.
the error i am getting is mention below :

```
Encountered internal error running command: Error: Cannot stop and clear com.android.chrome. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/Users/sivaranjani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s b8ee9091 shell pm clear com.android.chrome' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'Error: java.lang.SecurityException: PID 11584 does not have permission android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA to clear data of package com.android.chrome'; Code: '1'
```

What are the things i need to run to enable the mobile web in the real android device.Can anyone help in this

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem caused by MIUI, MI restricts executing commands on device through USB. To enable this, you have to enable **USB debugging(security settings)**, this can be found in the developer options.